# Rename 'htc-mytouch' to 'htc-mytouch-4g'?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-cleanup, retag-request

I just tapped into the [htc-mytouch](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htc-mytouch) (× 8) tag today on my walk through our tags. Checking with Wikipedia and GSMArena, I found no such device -- just a "HTC Mytouch 4g". Checking the questions, most of them explicitly name this device -- so I assume it is meant by the tag. Shouldn't we rename the tag then to [htc-mytouch-4g](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htc-mytouch-4g)? We already have [htc-mytouch-3g-slide] (× 7) to which it then would correspond, and further avoid confusion amongs our users.

Comment: I think there are 4 variants (3G, 3G Slide, 4G, and 4G Slide) so we may want to be careful.  Might be better to use the alternate names (Espresso, Sapphire, etc.) as the main tags with `mytouch-X` as synonyms.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with all the US variants (seems like every carrier uses his own brand). I guess the 'htc-mytouch' then was meant to collect everything but the 3g-slide? Makes not much sense to me (unless the slide is merged-in as well). Splitting a tag that rarely used (8Q in ~2y) makes no sense either.

Comment: @MatthewRead so how we want to go on from here? a) Merge them all into one 'htc-mytouch' tag, b) split the 'htc-mytouch' into 3 to cover each variant separately, c) leave them as-is?

Comment: I'm inclined to say we don't need to do anything.

Comment: I'm fine with that as well. So count my question as a "note of observation", and feel free to mark it 'status-declined' :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the loop: We're marking this [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) 'cause it doesn't seem like this is a necessary change. It's also a pretty small tag, so.